# Martingale convergence theorem in Polya's urn

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I want to get checked if my attempt is okay.

First off, let me shortly describe what Polya's urn is:

A certain urn initially contains a red and a blue ball. We now repeatedly do the following : we (uniformly at random) pick a ball from the urn, and then put it back in together with an additional ball of the same colour. Let $X_n$ denote the number of red balls and $Y_n$ denote the fraction of red balls after we’ve done this $n$ times, i.e. $$
Y_n = \frac{X_n}{n+2}. $$

And the following is my attempt so far. (let me assume that $Y_n$ is a martingale without showing it)

\begin{align*}
X_{n+1} &= X_n + 1_{\{\text{$n+1^{th}$ ball is red}\}} \\
X_n &= 1 + \sum_{1\leq i\leq n}1_{\{\text{$i^{th}$ ball is red}\}} \\
\to EX_n &= 1 + \sum_{1\leq i\leq n}E[1_{\{\text{$i^{th}$ ball is red}\}}] = 1 + nE[1_{\{\text{$i^{th}$ ball is red}\}}] = 1 + \frac{n}{2}
\end{align*}
since the indicator function take only values $0$ or $1$ with the same probability here (picking either ball has the same probability).

Thus, $EX_n = 1 + \frac{n}{2} = \frac{n+2}{2}$, so $EY_n = \frac{1}{2}$.

So now we know the expectation of $Y_n$, **but is it enough to say that $Y$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$**?

(where $Y_n\xrightarrow[]{a.s.}Y$ (Martingale convergence theorem))

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: If you know that $Y_n$ is a martingale, then obviously $\mathbb E[Y_n]=\mathbb E[Y_0]=1/2$. You're more or less proving that $Y_n$ is a martingale again. Also no, it is not enough, $Z_n:=1/2$ is a martingale with expectation $1/2$.

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks for letting me know. But how did you derive that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[Y_0] = 1/2$ by the fact that $Y_n$ is a martingale?

Comment: @PierrePC Also can you explain what I should show/prove in order to show that $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]] = \mathbb E[Y_n] = \cdots = \mathbb E[Y_0]$. About the uniform distribution of $Y$ in $[0,1]$, I'd have to think about it but I would use very different methods.

Comment: In any case, I don't think this question is research level, and I would advise you to post it on math.SE instead.

Comment: @PierrePC Thanks for your advise, but it's too late to delete this post and move it to math. I did not know the difference between here and math stack exchange, I won't happen it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, the distribution of $Y_n$ converges to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
More generally, if we initially have $r$ red and $b$ blue balls in the urn, then the distribution of the proportion of the red balls in the urn converges to the beta distribution with parameters $r,b$; see e.g. [Section 4](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~math_reu/proceedings/REU_Proceedings/Proceedings2008/2008Drinanepaged.pdf).

---

Moreover, in your case of $r=b=1$, letting 
$$p_{n,k}:=P(X_n=k),$$
it is easy to check directly by induction on $n$, using the recursion 
$$p_{n,k}=p_{n-1,k}\frac{n+1-k}{n+1}+p_{n-1,k-1}\frac{k-1}{n+1}$$
for natural $n$ and $k$, that 
$$p_{n,k}=\frac1{n+1}\,1\big\{k\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}\big\}$$
for $n=0,1,\dots$; that is, $X_n$ has the discrete uniform distribution on the set 
$\{1,\dots,n+1\}$.

Therefore, it is clear that the distribution of $Y_n=\frac{X_n}{n+2}$ converges to the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.